# SQL Query to return data under main rows with related data

Tags: sql-server

I'm sure this is probably on here somewhere but I couldn't anything and don't even know the proper way to ask the question.

Here's an example data set:

```
Table1
=======
IssueID     IssueTitle
1           Bug #1
2           Feature #1
3           Feature #2
4           Bug #2


Table2
======
IssueID     ActivityEntry
3           notes
3           attachment
2           notes
2           email
2           email
```

What I'd like is to use this query:

```
SELECT Table1.IssueID, Table1.IssueTitle 
FROM Table1 
WHERE IssueTitle like '%Feature%'
```

But also to include data from Table2 below each row of that result set so as to display like this:

```
IssueID     IssueTitle
----------------------
2       Feature #1
ActivityEntry
----------------------
notes
email
email

IssueID     IssueTitle
----------------------
3       Feature #2
ActivityEntry
----------------------
notes
attachment
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a `PIVOT` table.

Comment: What are you using to display the results?  SSRS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is:

```
SELECT Table1.IssueID,
    Table1.IssueTitle,
    Table2.ActivityEntry
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
    ON Table2.IssueID = Table1.IssueID
WHERE Table1.IssueTitle LIKE '%Feature%';
```

As for your display, that needs to be handled in your application or report designer.  SQL does columns, and all columns must be the same type.  The best you can do in SQL to approximate it is this, using two queries:

```
SELECT Table1.IssueID,
    Table1.IssueTitle
FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.IssueTitle LIKE '%Feature%';

SELECT Table2.ActivityEntry
FROM Table2
WHERE Table2.IssueID IN (
    SELECT Table1.IssueID
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Table1.IssueTitle LIKE '%Feature%'
    );
```

It would be much cleaner if `Table1` had an `IssueType` field with entries for Bug and Feature because `LIKE` is a very expensive operator, but that's a bit beyond the scope of the question.